# Finite State Machine for x/3

Tags: state-machines

I was asked to design a FSM for outputting x/3 without the remainder.

This should be implemented using a synchronous system defined as follows:

input: on each clock cycle t, one bit x[t]

output: on each clock cycle t, one bit y[t]

functionality:

let x be a number represented by concatenation of the input bits where x[t] is the LSB

let y be a number represented by concatenation of the output bits where y[t] is the LSB

so y is the result of x/3 (the floor function with x/3 as argument)

e.g.:

t 1 2 3 4

x[t] 1 0 1 0

y[t] 0 0 1 1

I am including two attempts, yet neither is actually yielding the correct result but rather the remainder (i.e. x mod 3), right? They were both intended to yield x/3 and yet it seems they both yield the remainder instead.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually, I think the state machine will emit both the division result and the remainder (which will be the state it is in at the end.) Have you considered the idea that you may need four states total? Also, is it true that you ONLY need to divide by 3?

Comment: @jonk Indeed I need only to divide by 3. I also realise the following: the result which the FSM is expected to yield can be categorized thus: if the remainder is null then the result should be the result of the previous state+1; if the remainder is 1, the result should be the result of the previous state+1 if 0 is added or the result of the previous state+2 if 1 is added; in case the remainder is 2, the result should be the result of the previous state+2. What do you think?

Comment: By the way, you realize that you need a counter, don't you?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I am later in this question expected to implement it using FFs, but for now I am only asked for the FSM.

Comment: Obviously if the number is large enough you need to store it somewhere. It's possible to build a million states state machine to support 333333 outputs, but it's crazy. You need three states, last one will change to first one and increment a counter.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Please see my comment above relating to jonk's comment. Namely, "I also realise the following: the result which the FSM is expected to yield can be categorized thus: if the remainder is null then the result should be the result of the previous state+1; if the remainder is 1, the result should be the result of the previous state+1 if 0 is added or the result of the previous state+2 if 1 is added; in case the remainder is 2, the result should be the result of the previous state+2." Of course that only holds for binary numbers greater than 10 in binary. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, something like that. You are managing remainer, so you will jump one or two states. When you complete a cycle, you increment the counter.

Comment: You make states "remainderIsZero", "remainderIsOne", "remainderIsTwo". So from zero you jump to one of the others, but don't increment. From 1 you jump to 2 without increment or to 0 with increment. From 2 you always jump with increment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you already did pretty much the right thing. The table looks like this:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& \textrm{bits:}\\
 & 0 & \quad1\\
\hline
\textrm{states:}\quad0 & 0:`0\textrm' & \quad1:`0\textrm'\\
1 & 2:`0\textrm' & \quad 0:`1\textrm'\\
2 & 1:`1\textrm' & \quad 2:`1\textrm'
\end{array}$$

You enter (start) at state 0 and then index into the table as bits arrive. So the state diagram looks like:

[image]

I've added the "emit" parts, as this is what is needed for you to get the quotient. (Obviously, the remainder is the state itself.) You will need some method of accumulating bits that are emitted (shift register, for example.)

Here are the results for all four-bit input values:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc}
\textrm{input} & \textrm{emitted output} & \textrm{remainder (state)}\\
\hline
0000 & 0000 & 0\\
0001 & 0000 & 1\\
0010 & 0000 & 2\\
0011 & 0001 & 0\\
0100 & 0001 & 1\\
0101 & 0001 & 2\\
0110 & 0010 & 0\\
0111 & 0010 & 1\\
1000 & 0010 & 2\\
1001 & 0011 & 0\\
1010 & 0011 & 1\\
1011 & 0011 & 2\\
1100 & 0100 & 0\\
1101 & 0100 & 1\\
1110 & 0100 & 2\\
1111 & 0101 & 0
\end{array}$$